# AwesomeWM promptbox background

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

How to set up background image for prompt box in awesomewm?

Tried:

- `mypromptbox:set_bg()` - Crash
- `mypromptbox:set_bgimage()` - Crash
- `mypromptbox:run({textbox = myWiboxBackgroundWidget})` - No result
- `mypromptbox = awful.widget.prompt({textbox = myWiboxBackgroundWidget})` - No result

Any ideas?

P.S. I need something like `mywibox[s]:set_bg(image)`, but for prompt box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the promptbox into a `wibox.widget.background` widget.

Comment: Would you give an example please? How do I construct wibox.widget.background?

Comment: Depends on your awesome version. In the simplest case it's just wibox.widget.background(promptbox, "#ff0000") (and this returns a new widget which you would then add to some wibox)